# Import JSON on Simple DB || SdbNavigator

Tags: json, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb, nosql

i'm trying to uplaod json file on simpleDB using **sdbNavigator** (chrome extension for simpeDB). I'm unable to do so.

I exported a json file from a simpeDB domain (table), so it must be valid, and tried to import it in another (newly created) domain. But facing the issue as shown in image.

I can add data manually but not by importing JSON.

- How can i do this?
- What's the issue that's preventing me to do this?

Please help.

[image]

**Update:**
I'm facing this issue when type of some attribute is array (multi-valued attribute). Otherwise, i'm able to import json

Example:

```
//This JSON works (i'm able to import it)

[{
    "itemName()": "EV_00",
    "name": "ABC",
    "webUrl": "asd",
    "address": "123"
}]

//Where as following JSON doesn't work. I face the issue while uploading it (As shown in figure above)
[{
    "itemName()": "EV_00",
    "name": ["ABC", "qwe"],
    "webUrl": "asd",
    "address": "123"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In SimpleDB all attributes have to be strings, so `["ABC", "qwe"]` is an invalid attribute.
If you do want to store it as an array, you could save it as a JSON string, i.e. `"]\"ABC\", \"qwe\"["`